# Is it possible to place demanding package on ssd?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, visual-studio-code

I'm planning to have dual-boot on my PC. Currently I have Windows and demanding programs (e.g. Photoshop, VS Code, so on...) on my SSD drive and games on my HDD. I want to split the SSD on 2 partitions:

- NTFs (for windows)
- ext4 (for linux packages)

And I want to split the HDD as follows:

- NTFS (windows games and programs)
- etx4 (root linux partition)

On linux I want demanding packages like VS Code on the SSD. And the issue is that I can't find the way to do it. Can you help me achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with having 2 partitions for the SSD (Windows, Linux) and having VSCode and others demanding programs on both OS'es? If you got space to install it, why not? Can't see what is the question.

Comment: linux root partition is going to be on hdd

Comment: What do you mean by Linux packages. Althiugh there are notable exceptions (Android, SNAP, Docker etc) Linux generally does.not run from packages - packages are.downloaded then installed onto the appropriate place in the drive - something of a cross between an App Store and program installer.

Comment: I mean those that are installed into /usr/bin xD